# How to set page numbering to start at chosen value in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm using this code to set autonumeration in generated Word doc and it works fine but I need to start numeration from specific value, e.g. page_1 - 3, page_2 - 4, page_3 - 5, etc.

```
//define currentpage object
object currentPage = WdFieldType.wdFieldPage;

activeWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter;

//set alignment  
activeWindow.ActivePane.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;

//Add page number  
activeWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(activeWindow.Selection.Range, ref currentPage, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

In Word you can set it by "Insert->Page Number->Format Page Numbers->Start at"
Is there equivalent property in C# for this?

**Solved!**
All we have to do is set this 2 property:

```
activeWindow.ActivePane.Selection.HeaderFooter.PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = true;               
activeWindow.ActivePane.Selection.HeaderFooter.PageNumbers.StartingNumber = 666;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I know of figuring out a way to do stuff in Word is by recording a Macro and then viewing the generated code. It's VB, but it's pretty easy to translate it into C#.
In Word 2007, if I record a macro that changes the Start at you're talking about I'm getting the following macro -

```
 Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    '
        With Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).PageNumbers
            .NumberStyle = wdPageNumberStyleArabic
            .HeadingLevelForChapter = 0
            .IncludeChapterNumber = False
            .ChapterPageSeparator = wdSeparatorHyphen
            .RestartNumberingAtSection = True
            .StartingNumber = 3
        End With
    End Sub
```

You're only interested in changing the StartingNumber property and the translation into C# is straightforward.